# Swift pdf not covering all cells in tableview

Tags: swift, pdf, tableview

I have researched this solution to sharing tableview cells via the UIActivityViewController, however, the number of rows in my tableView exceed the the heights shown here and so some of my tableview cells are 'cut off' on the resulting pdf/email/etc.

```
   let priorBounds: CGRect = self.tableView.bounds
    let fittedSize: CGSize = self.tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: priorBounds.size.width, height: self.tableView.contentSize.height))
    self.tableView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittedSize.width, height: fittedSize.height)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let pdfPageBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittedSize.width, height: (fittedSize.height))
    let pdfData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
    self.tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    self.tableView.bounds = priorBounds
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    let documentsFileName = documentDirectories! + "/" + "pdfName"
    pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
```

Am I right in thinking that the correct way to solve this is by increasing the depth of the fittedSize.height:

```
   let priorBounds: CGRect = self.tableView.bounds
    let fittedSize: CGSize = self.tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: priorBounds.size.width, height: self.tableView.contentSize.height))
    self.tableView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittedSize.width, height: fittedSize.height * 2.5)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let pdfPageBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittedSize.width, height: (fittedSize.height * 2.5))
    let pdfData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
    self.tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    self.tableView.bounds = priorBounds
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    let documentsFileName = documentDirectories! + "/" + "pdfName"
    pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
```

While this works it is not very pretty - I end with a lot of wasted space at the bottom of the pdf/email/etc AND of course it assumes that the list wont get longer than 2.5 times the fittedsize.height - Is there a better solution that knows where the bottom of the tableview cell is? Thank you.

Comment: are you able to solve this problem? I am also getting the same problem.

Comment: I have solved it although I am not sure that it is correct. That said it works for me. I created a height variable which was the number of items in my array * the tablerow height  + 120 (the 120 is random)  - I then replaced the fiited size height  of the tablebounds and the pdf bounds with my height.